# frequency-dependent network equivalent in time domain simulations

Tags: ltspice, frequency-response, oscillation

I have this question that has been haunting me for a while now. We all know that the first solution we think of when willing to account for frequency-dependent behavior in time-domain simulations, is the usage of equivalent networks deduced from fittings reproducing the same frequency-behavior.

My question is the following: why is it that running the equivalent circuit in transient simulations (I use LTspice) we do not get Gibbs phenomenon? The frequency-behavior is fitted up to a certain maximum frequency, right? Hence, a truncation of the frequency behavior.

Comment: Talking about the Gibbs phenomenon, do you mean ringing (relatively high frequency oscillations), accompanying sharp transitions in voltage/current graphs? As if some of your "frequency dependent network equivalent" components (typically RLCG, as I gather the FDNE model) are underdamped passive second order filters?

Comment: @V.V.T I mean the relatively high frequency oscillations.

Comment: And what about overvoltage spikes occasionally accompanying switching transients in unlucky configurations? Technically, they are the result of "ringing" in an underdamped network subcircuit. How come that there are no published FDNE simulations of these events?

Comment: @V.V.T There are. Check the publications of Gustavsen ;)

Comment: You are aware of published FDNE simulations that demonstrate ringing at discontinuities, and you ask why you do not see the ringing. I do not understand your question.

Comment: @V.V.T No! They demonstrate the accompanying switching transients in unlucky configurations which were experimentally validated. My question has been answered by Neil_Uk. See below.

Comment: Thank you for your question, it made me learn about the FDNE model. The model does not split the actual network into an assembly of subnetworks (as we do, for example, when deriving the telegrapher equation), but approximates a freq-vs-impedance table with rational function. No wonder this can produce non-physical phenomena (like power generation in a network of passive elements or causality break) that may appear in simulations.. Still, the model is powerful and widely used.

Comment: @V.V.T Glad it helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the Gibbs phenomenom when you truncate the frequency domain behaviour. If we do an FFT and ignore all frequencies above Fmax, that's effectively setting all response above Fmax to zero.

When we fit models of real component networks to a small number of frequencies up to Fmax, the network response doesn't 'stop' at Fmax, it carries on, being steadily attenuated, being defined by those components to as high a frequency as the time domain simulation handles. It's this steady attenuation that prevents Gibbs ripples from being seen.

Because we don't fit the network above Fmax, the response up there might be incorrect. However, if it's a low pass response (as it would be if we feel it's useful to stop fitting at high frequencies), the response will carry on dropping more or less smoothly, and will not exhibit the Gibbs phenomenom. It may be wrong, but it won't show Gibbs. You can make an estimate of the unfitted energy above Fmax, and use that to bound your expected error when you simulate the model.

Comment: even if the fitting stops at Fmax? and the generated network could potentially not be accurately representing the fitted response above Fmax?

Comment: @Wallflower Abosultely, I've added another paragraph to my answer to make that explicit. Like all computery things, [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). If you don't fit where you need to fit, then you are not going to see correct behaviour.

Comment: Very well explained! Thank you so much!